# Change just the date in Excel formula

Tags: excel, ms-office

I have the following excel formula in cell P3:
=AVERAGEIFS(H3:H8198, I3:I8198, "<=1/31/2023", I3:I8198, ">1/1/2023")

Followed by

cell P4:
=AVERAGEIFS(H3:H8198, I3:I8198, "<=12/31/2022", I3:I8198, ">12/1/2022")

cell P5:
=AVERAGEIFS(H3:H8198, I3:I8198, "<=11/30/2022", I3:I8198, ">11/1/2022")

cell P6:
=AVERAGEIFS(H3:H8198, I3:I8198, "<=10/31/2022", I3:I8198, ">10/1/2022")

cell P7:
=AVERAGEIFS(H3:H8198, I3:I8198, "<=9/30/2022", I3:I8198, ">9/1/2022")

cell P8:
=AVERAGEIFS(H3:H8198, I3:I8198, "<=8/31/2022", I3:I8198, ">8/1/2022")

cell P9:
=AVERAGEIFS(H3:H8198, I3:I8198, "<=7/31/2022", I3:I8198, ">7/1/2022")

cell P10:
=AVERAGEIFS(H3:H8198, I3:I8198, "<=6/30/2022", I3:I8198, ">6/1/2022")

cell P11:
=AVERAGEIFS(H3:H8198, I3:I8198, "<=5/31/2022", I3:I8198, ">5/1/2022")

cell P12:
=AVERAGEIFS(H3:H8198, I3:I8198, "<=4/30/2022", I3:I8198, ">4/1/2022")

cell P13:
=AVERAGEIFS(H3:H8198, I3:I8198, "<=3/31/2022", I3:I8198, ">3/1/2022")

cell P14:
=AVERAGEIFS(H3:H8198, I3:I8198, "<=2/38/2022", I3:I8198, ">2/1/2022")

This continues all the way down to cell P273 which is
=AVERAGEIFS(H3:H8198, I3:I8198, "<=7/31/2000", I3:I8198, ">7/1/2000")

Is there a simple way to change just the date VS manually changing 273 cells to different dates?

I tried selecting two or three cells and drag to the bottom of my column, hoping excel would understand I wanted to change just the year, but that did not work. Other parts of the formula get changed also such as the start and stop range.

Answer (score 1):

To lock the references we use `$` or absolute referencing: `$H$3:$H$8198` Then as it dragged down it will not change.

To change the year we can simply contatenate using some math and a row number:

```
"1/31/" & 2024-ROW($ZZ1)
```

Now as is is dragged down the $ZZ1, since the row reference is not absolute it will change and each row will subtract one more from the `2024`

```
=AVERAGEIFS($H$3:$H$8198, $I$3:$I$8198, "<=1/31/" & 2024-ROW($ZZ1), $I$3:$I$8198, ">1/1/" & 2024-ROW($ZZ1))
```

Comment: Could you please explain & 2024-ROW($ZZ1) a little bit. I see we are subtracting a row from 2024, but I am not following the ROW($ZZ1)

Comment: `ROW($ZZ1)` returns `1` and `ROW($ZZ2)` returns `2`   So as it is dragged down the row number will increase and we will subtract an ever larger number from `2024` which will return `2023`, then `2022`, then `2021` as it is dragged down.  That number gets concatenated with the rest of the string to effectively change the year by `-1` each row it is copied/dragged down.

Comment: Ok, now I am following that. What if changing just the year, I would like to change the entire date. Starting with 1/27/2023 and subtract one day all the way back to 07/21/2000?

Comment: `"<=" & (DATE(2023,1,27)- ROW($ZZ1))`